# JSON deserialize c# error

Tags: c#, json

I'm following this JSON deserialization example:
[Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp)

but I've run into a problem. My json file has a different structure.

```
"data": [
  {
     "id": "157156474316544_575441765821344",
     "from": {
        "name": "Testy McTest",
        "id": "624161969"
     },
     "message": "I am a message"...
```

So when I instantiate the serializer:

```
FacebookFeed facebookPosts = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FacebookFeed>(jsonFromWeb);
```

I get the error "No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'."

If anybody know how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it.

My structure is :

```
public class FacebookFeed
{
public List<FacebookPost> data { get; set; }
}

public class FacebookPost 
{
public string id        { get; set; }
public string from      { get; set; }
public string message   { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: from is an object but you have it marked down as a string?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `from` is an complex(it has several user attributes/properties - id, name) object but you've declared it as plain string. 
Try something like:

```
public class Sender
{
public string id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
}

public class FacebookPost 
{
public string id        { get; set; }
public Sender from      { get; set; }
public string message   { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'from' is an object, not a string. Thus you are getting the error "No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'."